# Returning CDI bean reference in EJB call

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Is the following allowed in Java EE?

I have a `@Singleton` session bean that works as a registry and  automatically discovers certain strategies that are used throughout the application, like this:

```
public interface Strategy {
    Class<?> supportedType();
}

@Singleton
public class StrategyRegistry {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Strategy> strategies;

    private Map<Class<?>, Strategy> registry = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        Iterator<Strategy> it = strategies;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Strategy s = it.next();
            registry.put(s.supportedType(), s);
        }
    }

    // return provided strategy to caller
    public Strategy strategyFor(Class<?> clz) {
        return registry.get(clz);
    }
}
```

Now my questions is whether sharing the `@Inject`ed CDI beans to other clients (via `#strategyFor(...)`) is allowed or whether this can lead to unexpected behavior or side effects?

The strategies are stateless and thread-safe, so in general it should be possible to use them concurrently.

Note that the owner of the CDI beans above is a `@Singleton` and the CDI beans are currently `@Dependent`, so if I'm reading the spec correctly they should be available for the whole lifetime of the application.

Originally we used EJB stateless beans, and `strategyFor(...)` only returned the proxy to the actual bean, which I considered reasonably safe.  This is no longer possible on Wildfly 8 with recent WELD versions, and thus we switched to CDI beans.  With CDI beans, however, the actual bean is returned, not a proxy.

If this is not allowed, is the following a safe alternative?

```
@Inject private BeanManager beanManager;

public Strategy strategyFor(Class<?> clz) {
    Strategy s = registry.get(clz);
    if (s == null) return null;
    return beanManager.getReference(s.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just inject the Strategy at the required location and make it @ApplicationScoped/@Singelton?

Comment: They are not known at Compiler time.

Comment: Then use @Produces and then do normal injection.

Comment: Your suggestions are welcome, but the above code/use case is vastly simplified to show a minimal example in this question. I'm well aware of programmatic lookup, but for reasons beyond the scope of this question "simple" injection is not suitable here, hence my actually *very specific* question of whether sharing CDI bean references between beans is allowed.

Comment: I don't see why not, as @Depend (default scope) is a pseudo scope therefor the bean manager is no longer interested in the bean. Its life cycle from there on depends purely on the outer bean or other classes that hold direct references to it - Its a plain old POJO

Comment: @dngfng That makes sense - if you make your comment an answer I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not, as @Depend (default scope) is a pseudo scope therefor the bean manager is no longer interested in the bean. Its life cycle from there on depends purely on the outer bean or other classes that hold direct references to it - Its a plain old POJO

Answer (score 1):

See the following

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,TYPE,PARAMETER})
public interface StrategyContext {

    //Nonbinding and default so that you can have one producer method for all strategies
    @NonBinding
    Class<?> supportedType() default Object.class;
}

@Singleton
public class StrategyRegistry {

    private Map<Class<?>, Strategy> registry = new HashMap<>();

    @Inject
    void startup(@Any final Instance<Strategy> strategies) {
        for(Strategy strategy:strategies)
            registry.put(Strategy.supportedType(), Strategy);
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @StrategyContext
    @ApplicationScoped
    public Strategy strategyFor(final InjectionPoint ip) {
       final StrategyContext sc = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(StrategyContext.class);
       final Class<?> supportedType = sc.supportedType();
       return registry.get(supportedType);
    }
}
```

And then wherever you want to use it.

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {

   @Inject
   @StrategyContext(supportedType=MySupportedType.class)
   private Strategy strategy;

}
```

On the producer and the injection point:

> NOTE
>   If at runtime, the strategy may not exist and hence the method may return null, then annotate the producer with @Dependent, not @ApplicationScope and hence at the injection point, don't inject the raw strategy, but:

```
  @Inject
    @StrategyContext(supportedtype=MySupportedType.class)
    private Instance<Strategy> strategy

    ...
    if(!strategy.isUnsatisfied()) { strategy.get().doSomething();}
```

Comment: This look like a really elegant solution to me.